# steam.sh is empty

Tags: steam

I tried to install Steam on my 64 bits PC, but when I tried to run it it did nothing. I then tried to run the program via terminal, and all I got was this message:

> /usr/bin/steam: line 192: /home/pauix/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Success

Seeing that there was something wrong with the file "steam.sh", I decided to check it, and it was completely empty (which I guess it shouldn't be). Is there any way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which Ubuntu version are you running?

Comment: Please re-install steam using these instructions. [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve) To remove steam open a **Terminal** with _Ctrl+Alt+T_ and type: `sudo apt-get --purge remove steam && rm -rm ~/.local/share/Steam`

Answer (score 4):

Based on efthialex's comments, uninstall Steam like this:

```
sudo apt-get purge steam
rm ~/.local/share/Steam -rf
```

then reinstall using:

```
sudo dpkg -i steam_latest.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

A new windows will pop out, click on the button *Start Steam*.

Comment: Be careful with the `rm` command. To prevent errors, I have swapped the directory and options, so you cannot accidentally run `rm -rf ~/.local/` or something.

Comment: Another way to recursively remove the `Steam` directory while minimizing the risk of bad mistakes is `cd ~/.local/share && rm -rf Steam`. This has the advantage that even if an extra space is added by accident and not noticed, no significant data loss will occur.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the script and run Steam again.

```
rm home/$USER/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh
```

This will generate some error messages and then Steam will reconfigure.